# Inserting a JS object into $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to insert an object formatted like this:

```
$scope.newObj = {1: "N/A", 2: "KO", 3: "OK", 4: "OK", 5: "OK", 15: "N/A", 19: "OK"}
```

I tried using the following for loop:

```
var objt = $scope.newObject;
      console.log($scope.newObject[0]) // undefined
for(i=0;i<$scope.newObj.length;i++)
{
   $http.post("insert?etat="+$scope.newObject[0]+"&id="+Object.keys(objt)) 
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I am getting `undefined` everywhere.  Does anyone have an idea on how to retrieve the data from that object row by row then insert the values to the service?

Comment: Can you show what a sample `$http.post` would look like?

Comment: Are `newObj` and `newObject` different things or is that a typo?

Comment: This is really confusing since you have mismatched variable names , and an array loop but no array is mentioned. Please see [ask] and provide all relevant details. It's not clear what you are working with or what expected results are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

newObj is an object rather than a array. You have tried to use it like a  array. So just a iteration code needs to modify:

**Use the following code:**

```
var objt = $scope.newObject;
for(var key in objt)
{
   $http.post("insert?etat="+objt[key]+"&id="+key) 
}
```

Comment: best to use `if(objt.hasOwnProperty(key)` or loop over `Object.keys(objt)` However I don't think this is what OP is trying to do